# How can I reduce or flatten an array of arrays using the Array.concat() method inside the callback function for Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, reduce

```
//Bonus - uncomment lines 15 and 17
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.reduce((a,c) => a + c);
// The below line should console.log: ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

I'm new to using the reduce function and it's a little bit complicated.

I'm trying to flatten the nested array but I don't really know what to do next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Remember, before asking a new question ___try searching SO for already existing answers___. If an already existing answer does not (fully) answer your question it's then great to start a new question referencing the existing question and elaborate further what's unanswered. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As you already got an answer from @CertainPerformance remember to accept if it answers your question.

Comment: Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18307218/5698098) answer for the already mentioned question [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025/5698098) answers your question completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned the solution already, you just need to implement it - `concat` the current item to the accumulator inside the `reduce` callback:

```js
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c));
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

But `.flat()` would be much easier:

```js
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.flat();
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option - flatMap:

```js
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.flatMap(a => a);
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

But it is only really advantageous if you want to do something inside the map, like this:

```js
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.flatMap(a => a.concat(a));
console.log(flattenedArray);
```

Or like this:

```js
const arrays = [["how", "now"], ["brown", "cow"]];
const flattenedArray = arrays.flatMap(a => a.map(b => b.toUpperCase()));
console.log(flattenedArray);
```